# php потоковая передача видео

Tags: php

Может кто знает как сделать на php потоковую передачу видео файла. Использовал как тут https://gist.github.com/ranacseruet/9826293 это робит, но на iphone не работает и падает ошибка ( Unhandled Promise Rejection: AbortError: The operation was aborted. )

Comment: https://github.com/micilini/video-stream

Comment: Это работает как же я скинул https://gist.github.com/ranacseruet/9826293  и не будет работать нормально на iphone

Comment: На 99.99% уверен что никто не поможет со скриптом по вашей ссылке, ибо, во-первых, старый код и вряд ли поддерживаемый\обновляемый, во-вторых, это надо самому поднимать сервер, ставить скрипты и т.п. при всем уважении, желания чуть меньше чем ноль подобным заниматься.